# Are the bounded continuous functions separating for the set of probability measures?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space and $\mathcal M_1(E,\mathcal E)$ denote the space of probability measures on $(E,\mathcal E)$. A class $\mathcal C$ of real-valued bounded $\mathcal E$-measurable functions on $E$ is called *separating* for $\mathcal M_1(E,\mathcal E)$ if $$\left(\forall f\in\mathcal C:\int f\:{\rm d}(\mu-\nu)=0\right)\Rightarrow \mu=\nu\tag1$$ for all $\mu,\nu\in\mathcal M_1(E,\mathcal E)$.

> Assume $E$ is a metric space and $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$. I know that if consider the set $\tilde{\mathcal M}_1(E,\mathcal E)$ of Radon probability measures on $(E,\mathcal E)$, then the set of $[0,1]$-valued Lipschitz functions on $E$ with Lipschitz constant $1$ is separating for $\tilde{\mathcal M}_1(E,\mathcal E)$.
>
> Can we generally show the weaker result that the set of $C_b(E)$ of real-valued bounded continuous on $E$ is separating for $\mathcal M_1(E,\mathcal E)$? If not, is there at least an easier proof for the claim "$C_b(E)$ is separating for $\tilde{\mathcal M}_1(E,\mathcal E)$" available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.** If $\mu(F) = \nu(F)$ for all closed subsets $F$ of $E$, then $\mu = \nu$.

*Sketch of the proof.* The set of all subsets $A$ of $E$ such that $\mu(A) = \nu(A)$ is a $\lambda$-system. It contains the closed subsets, which form a $\pi$-system that generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Use the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem to conclude.

**Lemma** If $\int f \mathrm{d}\mu = \int f \mathrm{d}\nu$ for every $f \in C_b(E)$, then $\mu(F) = \nu(F)$ for all closed subsets $F$ of $E$.

*Sketch of the proof.* Let $F \subset E$ be closed. For each integer $n \geqslant 1$, let $f_n \colon E \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $f_n(x) = \min\{n d(x,F), 1\}$. Then $f_n$ is in $C_b(E)$ and the sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $\mathbf{1}_F$, and is decreasing: $f_n(x) \downarrow \mathbf{1}_F(x)$. By the Beppo-Levi theorem (monotone convergence), $\int f_n \mathrm{d}\mu \to \mu(F)$ and $\int f_n \mathrm{d}\nu \to \nu(F)$.

Comment: Am I missing something or can we conclude $\mu=\nu$ in your last lemma? $\mathcal B(E)$ should be generated by the closed subsets and so this should be true. I'm unsure since I've read that the weak limit of probability measures on $E$ is only unique when $E$ is Polish. But if $E$ is separating for the probability measures on $E$, shouldn't this yield the uniqueness of the weak limits?

Answer (score 0):

This seems doable. Suppose $G$ is open, and set $f_n(x) = \min\{ n d(x,E\cap G^c), 1\}$. Then $f_n$ increases up to $1_G$, and $f_n$ is continuous and bounded. This with monotone convergence implies that $\mu(G) =\nu(G)$.